# ldd shows .so not found but RUNPATH contains the lib

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, nixos, runpath

I'm trying to get some binaries running on NixOS, and I ran into a weird situation when trying to get `ldd` to find `libpython2.7.so.1.0` and other libs.

```
$ ldd lldb
./lldb: /nix/store/5rjfisjzz6vgwmgf7zx25yd9p6rfs0zy-ncurses-6.2-abi5-compat/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by ./lldb)
./lldb: /nix/store/5rjfisjzz6vgwmgf7zx25yd9p6rfs0zy-ncurses-6.2-abi5-compat/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /nix/store/nn8pr7xzam0rz7fq95x9dpi087xazsnv-theos/share/theos/toolchain/linux/iphone/usr/bin/./../lib/liblldb.so.10git)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd57b80000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f921e821000)
    liblldb.so.10git => /nix/store/nn8pr7xzam0rz7fq95x9dpi087xazsnv-theos/share/theos/toolchain/linux/iphone/usr/bin/./../lib/liblldb.so.10git (0x00007f9215c3c000)
    libz.so.1 => /nix/store/1l4r0r4ab3v3a3ppir4jwiah3icalk9d-zlib-1.2.11/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9215c1f000)
    librt.so.1 => /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9215c12000)
    libdl.so.2 => /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9215c0d000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /nix/store/5rjfisjzz6vgwmgf7zx25yd9p6rfs0zy-ncurses-6.2-abi5-compat/lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f9215ba7000)
    libm.so.6 => /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9215a66000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /nix/store/c9f15p1kwm0mw5p13wsnvd1ixrhbhb12-gcc-10.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9215891000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /nix/store/c9f15p1kwm0mw5p13wsnvd1ixrhbhb12-gcc-10.3.0-lib/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9215875000)
    libc.so.6 => /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f92156b0000)
    /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f921e843000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => not found
    libncurses.so.5 => not found
    libform.so.5 => not found
    libpanel.so.5 => not found
    libuuid.so.1 => not found
    libedit.so.2 => not found
    libxml2.so.2 => not found
```

There are quite a few missing, but let's focus on `libpython2.7.so.1.0`. When we check the `RUNPATH` of `ld64`,

```
$ readelf -d ld64 | rg RUNPATH
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/nix/store/c9f15p1kwm0mw5p13wsnvd1ixrhbhb12-gcc-10.3.0-lib/lib:/nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib:/nix/store/xvyzi7cr0icnyavi5pm9rywjc4d8l7sx-libedit-20210714-3.1/lib:/nix/store/yxflij8cg4fgnzqmda91jx4d94jvkjf5-util-linux-2.37.2-lib/lib:/nix/store/370lxynzkmwrk8685jx9p2vgh7h0xp2h-libxml2-2.9.12/lib:/nix/store/5rjfisjzz6vgwmgf7zx25yd9p6rfs0zy-ncurses-6.2-abi5-compat/lib:/nix/store/nvx0l614cv661i5zz6w3j3y2w1xzppv1-python-2.7.18/lib:/nix/store/7344a20iqaja6i2qdz2xrgzy28rgnz5p-util-linux-2.37.2-lib/lib:/nix/store/1l4r0r4ab3v3a3ppir4jwiah3icalk9d-zlib-1.2.11/lib:$ORIGIN/../lib]
```

it contains `/nix/store/nvx0l614cv661i5zz6w3j3y2w1xzppv1-python-2.7.18/lib`, which has our desired lib,

```
$ file /nix/store/nvx0l614cv661i5zz6w3j3y2w1xzppv1-python-2.7.18/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
/nix/store/nvx0l614cv661i5zz6w3j3y2w1xzppv1-python-2.7.18/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

I'm not sure how this is possible. The executable is also 64-bit, as we can see here:

```
$ file lldb
lldb: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure how this is possible.

There is a big difference between `RUNPATH` and `RPATH`: the former applies *only* to the binary itself (in this case, only to the `lldb` binary), the latter applies to the binary *and all its dependencies*.

Effectively using `RUNPATH` forces *all* binaries participating in the (dynamic) link to be linked correctly (to specify their own `RUNPATH` so that every one of their (recursive) dependencies is found).

What you observe is possible if:

1. `lldb` does not *itself* depend on `libpython.2.7.so.1.0` and
2. one of `lldb`s dependencies *does* depend on on `libpython.2.7.so.1.0` and
3. that dependency *itself* does not have a `RUNPATH` in which `libpython.2.7.so.1.0` can be found.

You can verify that 1) is true with `readelf -d ./lldb | grep libpython` (I predict there will be no output).

If 1) is true, we know that 2 is true because `libpython` shows up in `ldd` output. You can find *which* of `lldb`s *direct* dependencies this is by going through them one by one (you can see them in the output from `readelf -d lldb | grep NEEDED`).

Once you found a dependency which needs `libpython`, you can confirm 3) by using `readelf -d $direct_dependency | grep R.*PATH`.